# nmcli connection import type wireguard writes additional default route - How to avoid it?

Tags: linux, vpn, networkmanager, wireguard, nmcli

At start I have:

```
[root@client ~]# ip ro | grep default
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100
```

When i say

```
nmcli connection import type wireguard file /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
```

I get

```
[root@client ~]# ip ro | grep default
default dev wg0 proto static scope link metric 50 
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100
```

At this moment I lost connection to remote host.

What can I do to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Don't import it into NetworkManager.

Comment: So, what is the correct way to create and up wg-interface without using wg-quick?

Comment: What do you mean by "without using wg-quick"? That is how you do it.

Comment: Nope. I don't use wg-quick. Instead of it I just use nmcli for import wg-interface, then nmcli connection modify and then nmcli connection up wg0.

Comment: I gave up wq-quick, just because it creating his own routes, that doesn't work for me. Nmcli is the way, I hope, that will let me do more control over routes. May be there's another, more suitable, way?

Comment: If you don't want a route, then do not put it in AllowedIPs.

Comment: If I comment AllowedIPs in server config in Peer section and send ```wg syncconf...```, i get this (from server):
```ping 10.112.0.6
PING 10.112.0.6 (10.112.0.6) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.112.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Required key not available
```
And no handshakes.

But when I uncomment it back again and resync config, it start work:
```ping 10.112.0.6
PING 10.112.0.6 (10.112.0.6) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.112.0.6: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=7.26 ms
64 bytes from 10.112.0.6: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=47.8 ms```

Comment: That sounds like it is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound right. Are you using a rather old version of NetworkManager? Which?

Seems you have a `0.0.0.0/0` route as AllowedIPs. That is fine (if that is what you want). NetworkManager should configure the routes as `wg-quick` would, and as described in https://www.wireguard.com/netns/#improved-rule-based-routing.

In particular, check all the routes with `ip route show table all` and the corresponding routing rules with `ip rule`.

This automatism is controlled by the `wireguard.ip4-auto-default-route` setting in the (imported) profile. You can inspect the imported profile with `nmcli con show wg0`.

But it also depends on your actual settings. For example, if `wg0.conf` has `Table=off` or a fixed table number, then this is different (both with `wg-quick` and with the profile that you imported in NetworkManager). It would be better to show the complete configuration (**after masking private data!!**), otherwise it's just guess work what happens.